# Servlet mapping with multiple (two) wildcards separated by slash

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, url-pattern

I am trying to map a servlet pattern that matches both

```
/server/abcDef/1432124/adfadfasdfa
```

and

```
/server/abcDef/abcd/12345
```

The values '1432124' and 'abcd' are not fixed and could be a multitude of values. So essentially I need to match against `/abcDef/*/*` -- only the *abcDef* is fixed.

Is there a way for me to map this? Really I am looking for something like the following:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>abcDefServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/server/abcDef/*/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Servlet Specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html), URL patterns ending with "/*" will match all requests to the preceding path.
So, in the way you were doing it, you'd have to enter the following **url** to get to abcDefServlet:

```
http://myapp.com/server/abcDef/*/<wildcard>
```

What you can do though is add multiple URL patterns in one servlet mapping. E.g:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>abcDefServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/server/abcDef/1432124/*</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>/server/abcDef/abcd/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

**Update:**

Since `1432124` and `abcd` are not fixed values, you can safely add the following mapping:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>abcDefServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/server/abcDef/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then treat whatever values that come after `abcDef` inside the servlet itself, with the following function:

```xml
req.getPathInfo()
```

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned that '1432124' and 'abcd' are not fixed and could be a multitude of values. So essentially i need to match against /abcDef/*/* -- only the abcDef is fixed. I will edit my question to be very clear.

Comment: @Sai: Ok. I have now updated the answer as well. Please check it.