# Defining alias for Servlet context

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Is there a way to define alias for a Servlet context?

If I want that

- `http://server/a/foo-servlet` and `http://server/b/foo-servlet` point to the same Servlet (or `http://server/a/foo.jsp` and `http://server/b/foo.jsp` for that matter)
- calling `HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()` in the foo Servlet (or `foo.jsp`) returns `/a` or `/b` respectively

my only option seems to be to deploy the web application containing the foo Servlet twice. Correct?

If I define two contexts `a` and `b` both pointing to the same doc base the container would essentially still deploy two individual applications.

Comment: Why you need different alias for the same application? What you want to achieve?

Comment: Add two [`url-pattern` elements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16867899/2071828). Map the exact same servlet to two different url patterns.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think, OP is talking about the different context root not just different path to the same Servlet but I am confused with the `server` in the OP's sample and talking about `getContextPath()` method as well.

Comment: You could deploy it to /foo, then use a ROOT context with HttpRewriteFilter to rewrite the URLs. There might be a better way, though.

Comment: "different context root not just different path to the same Servlet" - yes, that's correct. I updated the question that make that a little clearer.

Comment: You can use apache to create aliases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11721966/289396 is what you're looking for?

Comment: @LeosLiterak, "use apache to create aliases" - true, but that doesn't solve the `HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()` problem.

Comment: @JoseK, the question you referenced describes how to deploy the same WAR file more than once under different contexts. I know I _could_ do that but I was wondering whether there's a way around it.

Comment: @MarcelStör: I assumed it's still a single WAR rather than deploying twice - I thought which was what you wanted? Okay doesn't look to be so straightforward then